# "Why I can't I" or "why can I not"?

Tags: grammar

Tell me please which one of the following sentences is correct.

> Why **can't I** use this app, but I can use the other one.
>
> Why **can I not** use this app, but I can use the other one.

I suspect that both sentence could be correct, if so, then which one is more formal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both sentences are fine. People speak differently I don't believe there's a difference besides the **contraction**.